# Completely hide SideNavigation

Tags: sapui5, slide

I am using `sap.tnt.SideNavigation` in my app. I also found out how to collapse it so that only Images are shown. But this isn't enough. I want to completely hide the side navigation. So that the whole screen is filled with content.

Thank you

Comment: you really should post some code so we can assist. What is your root view and how does your controller look for example.

Comment: sorry forgott the links The View[link](https://github.com/Mabenan/MediaServer/blob/master/src/webapp/view/App.view.xml)
The Controller [link](https://github.com/Mabenan/MediaServer/blob/master/src/webapp/controller/App.controller.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you, It is just a work around if any one has the proper solution kindly share.

Using the CSS you can achieve it, you need to add your custom class to `sap.tnt.SideNavigation` so that below CSS should not override the default CSS.

```
.yourCustomClass.sapTntSideNavigation.sapTntSideNavigationNotExpandedWidth {
    margin-left: -50px;
}

.yourCustomClass.sapTntSideNavigation,
.yourCustomClass.sapTntSideNavigation.sapTntSideNavigationNotExpandedWidth {
    transition: 1s;
}
```

Comment: yeah this helped that the side navigation isn't shown anymore. Now i try to figure out how to override the padding-left: 3rem of
`.sap-desktop .sapTntToolPageAsideCollapsed .sapTntToolPageAside + .sapTntToolPageMain`
as this results in a whitespace where the side navigation was.

Comment: found a dirty solution.

I added this to the body of the index.html

```
 <style type="text/css" scoped>
  .hideSide.sapTntSideNavigation.sapTntSideNavigationNotExpandedWidth {
   margin-left: -50px;
  }

  .hideSide.sapTntSideNavigation,
  .hideSide.sapTntSideNavigation.sapTntSideNavigationNotExpandedWidth {
   transition: 1s;
  }

  .sap-desktop .sapTntToolPageAsideCollapsed .sapTntToolPageAside+.sapTntToolPageMain,
  .sap-tablet .sapTntToolPageAsideCollapsed .sapTntToolPageAside+.sapTntToolPageMain {
   padding-left: 0rem
  }
 </style>
```

Comment: Can't you just retrieve the control and use the method `setVisible(false)`?

Comment: hm you are right this would do something similiar to what inizios style code does. But it has the disadvantag that you have to toogle it visible manually. And the whitespace will also persist.